# Standard functions and operations not working in class constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, filebuf

I am trying to make my first class with a constructor and it seems to be acting strangely.
My class is derived from `filebuf` and for some reason, I am unable to open it in the constructor.
I tried to add a `cout` statement for debugging, but the `<<` operator is not recognized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bin.h"

int main()
{
    bin myBin("e:\Temp\test.txt");


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

bin.h

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

class bin : private std::filebuf {

int buffSize = 1000;
char* buffer;
unsigned int length;
short int buffCounter;

public:
    bin(std::string fileName)
    {
        open(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        if (!is_open())
            std::cout << "ERROR: failed to open file " << fileName << std::endl;

        //set all IO operations to be unbufferred, buffering will be managed manually
        setbuf(0, 0);
        //create buffer
        buffer = new char[buffSize];

    };


     virtual ~bin()
    {
        delete buffer;
    };
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
std::cout << "ERROR: failed to open file " << fileName << std::endl;
```

Should be

```
std::cout << "ERROR: failed to open file " << fileName.c_str() << std::endl;
```

`std::cout` doesn't always accept `std::string` but does accept `const char *`

Comment: I am a little confused over this arguement: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4168e5b7507e6e42

Comment: Yeah this is totally false, `std::string` has an overloaded [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

Comment: @Barry - the reason why I put this answer was because the asker of the question put on a comment to Steephen's answer that 'error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\mt\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\cipher\cipher\bin.h 18' which is why I put this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
bin myBin("e:\Temp\test.txt");
```

You have to correct above line as follows:

```
bin myBin("e:\\Temp\\test.txt");
```

DEMO: http://cpp.sh/7b4k

Comment: I corrected it and I still get the same build error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\users\mt\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\cipher\cipher\bin.h 18

Comment: @Person93 please refer the demo,  it is working after this change

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: It's included in the cpp file where the main function is.

Comment: @Person93 it is very bad practice to write headers that don't include all their dependencies, since it is *very* easy to mess them up.

Comment: I do not intend to use cout in the class, only while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

To use `std::string` you need:

```
#include <string>
```

The `iostream` include may have forward-declared `std::string` but without the full definition you don't get `operator<<` (or `c_str()`).

Some other answerers may be unable to reproduce your problem because different standard libraries might have their `iostream` fully do `#include <string>` (this is permitted but not required).